# C# Quickly checking if two pictureboxes touch each other?

Tags: touch, collision-detection, picturebox

I'm creating my first non-console game in Visual C#.
I have a player which is a picturebox, and obstacles which are also pictureboxes.
Now when I create an obstacle (picturebox) at a random position, I would like to check if it already touches an other obstacle.

Here's what I have now:

```
Picturebox obstacles = new Picturebox[20];
for (int i = 0; i < obstacles.Length; i++)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    Random randomNumber = new Random(date.Second * (date.Minute / 2) ^ 2 + date.Hour * 123 + (i ^ 9 + i / 2));
    obstacles[i] = new PictureBox();
    obstacles[i].Image = Properties.Resources.es;
    obstacles[i].Size = new Size(25, 50);
    obstacles[i].Location = new Point(randomNumber.Next(640 - obstacles[i].Image.Width), randomNumber.Next(topBar.Height, 480 - obstacles[i].Image.Height));
    if (IsTouching(obstacles[i], player))
    {
        i--;
    }
    else
    {
        bool tmp = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < obstacles.Length; j++)
        {
            if (obstacles[j] != null && j != i)
            {
                if (IsTouching(obstacles[j], obstacles[i]))
                {
                    tmp = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (tmp)
        {
            Controls.Add(obstacles[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

So that's my way, but I know it's not really effective, so any better ideas, cause it takes a while (~5 seconds) to create those obstacles.
And here's my IsTouching method, which also kinda sucks, anyone have better ideas?

```
private bool IsTouching(PictureBox obj1, PictureBox obj2)
{
    Point[] obj1Points = new Point[(obj1.Width * obj1.Height) - ((obj1.Width - 2) * (obj1.Height - 2))];
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = obj1.Left + 1; x < obj1.Left + obj1.Width - 1; x++)
    {
        obj1Points[count] = new Point(x, obj1.Top);
        obj1Points[count + 1] = new Point(x, obj1.Top + obj1.Height);
        count += 2;
    }
    for (int y = obj1.Top; y < obj1.Top + obj1.Height; y++)
    {
        obj1Points[count] = new Point(obj1.Left, y);
        obj1Points[count + 1] = new Point(obj1.Left + obj1.Width, y);
        count += 2;
    }

    Point[] obj2Points = new Point[(obj2.Width * obj2.Height) - ((obj2.Width - 2) * (obj2.Height - 2))];
    count = 0;
    for (int x = obj2.Left + 1; x < obj2.Left + obj2.Width - 1; x++)
    {
        obj2Points[count] = new Point(x, obj2.Top);
        obj2Points[count + 1] = new Point(x, obj2.Top + obj2.Height);
        count += 2;
    }
    for (int y = obj2.Top; y < obj2.Top + obj2.Height; y++)
    {
        obj2Points[count] = new Point(obj2.Left, y);
        obj2Points[count + 1] = new Point(obj2.Left + obj2.Width, y);
        count += 2;
    }

    for (int obj2Point = 0; obj2Point < obj2Points.Length; obj2Point++)
    {
        for (int obj1Point = 0; obj1Point < obj1Points.Length; obj1Point++)
        {
            if (obj2Points[obj2Point].X == obj1Points[obj1Point].X && obj2Points[obj2Point].Y == obj1Points[obj1Point].Y)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What it does: Checks if the given two parameters edges touch each other. So basically just a collision-detection, anyone have any ideas, cause I'm kinda new at this stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that all the obstacles are solid (i.e. 2 obstacles touch if the other is inside the other), you can use the following method:

```
private bool IsTouching(PictureBox p1, PictureBox p2)
{
    if (p1.Location.X + p1.Width < p2.Location.X) 
        return false;
    if (p2.Location.X + p2.Width < p1.Location.X)
        return false;
    if (p1.Location.Y + p1.Height < p2.Location.Y)
        return false;
    if (p2.Location.Y + p2.Height < p1.Location.Y)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I tested your current `IsTouching` method and found out that it fails in some corner cases, such as in [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW5U4.png) (it claims they are not touching although they are). My method works in these corner cases too.

Answer (score -1):

There is one simple line of code for this but it might also fail for some corner pieces sometimes.

```
if(player1.Bounds.IntersectWith(player2.Bounds){
  //Do something
}
```

Replace player1 with the name of the picture box and the same with player2 ofc.